# Eclipse cannot resolve to a type that actually exists

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am getting the following error:

```
Mapping cannot be resolved to a type
```

When I do the import of the class I need, it appears as a valid class to import, but when cleaning the project, I obtain the error. This is the situation:

[image: Import error]

I tried cleaning, restarting eclipse and all the common stuff, but nothing seems to work.

Do you know how to solve this?

Regards!

Comment: `instance` is a reserved word. Don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: instanceof is a reserved word...

Comment: @Ravinder `instance` is not a reserved word. `instanceof` is, though.

Comment: Note the red squiggles under your import - I would have a look at that error first.

Comment: @JonSkeet The error there is: "The import io.projection cannot be resolved". However, that package does exist.

Comment: I assume that Mapping is an interface, have you tried using a class?

Comment: what's wrong with using an interface?

Comment: So once you've fixed *that* error, the rest will be fixed. Now, please tell us *where* that package exists - in a jar file? In your source code? We have very little context.

Comment: @pshemek: That's absolutely not the problem. The `io.projection` package itself can't be found, and an interface should be fine here anyway.

Comment: are you using maven? If so try mvn eclipse:eclipse. Or did this error showed up after a merge with an svn tool? If so, refresh the package.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. The package actually exists in another project imported in the build path (Projects tab). This project was initially imported via GitHub (https://github.com/jorgearaujo/projection). The Eclipse version I'm using is Kepler.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: Yes, my mistake. Just commented looking at the pink underline from the errors posted.

Comment: Although, I have another projects imported in the same way and they work.

Comment: @GregDeckers I'm using Maven only for dependencies.